# Transformar imagem em array de bytes

Tags: android, imageview

Tenho uma imagem que está em um `ImageView` no Android e preciso converter a imagem em array de bytes para enviar ao MySQL. Como poderia fazer?

Comment: De onde veio a imagem?

Comment: A imagem é carregada do dispositivo para o ImageView

Answer (score 2):

Use este método:

```
public byte[] convertImageViewToByteArray(ImageView image){
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

Nota: O método assume que a imagem foi atribuída à ImageView com `android:src`.
Caso tenha sido com `android:background` em vez de

```
image.getDrawable()
```

use

```
image.getBackground()
```

Comment: No caso estou pegando uma imagem do dispositivo e setando no ImageView, o processo será o mesmo?

Comment: Como assim? Explique melhor.

Comment: Tenho um ImageView e ao clicar nele pego uma imagem da galeria do dispositivo e carrego nele a partir dai ao clicar no botão salvar ele envia ao banco de dados

Comment: Continuo sem perceber. Se quer, conforme perguntou, converter a imagem que está na ImageView para Byte[] use o método da resposta. Se tem outra pergunta crie uma nova com os detalhes necessários .